# View QTVR files with Google Cardboard

Tags: quicktime, image-editing, macos

I have a lot of old QuickTime VR cubic panorama images which I want to view with my Google Cardboard, preferably using Google Cardboard iOS app. I think for this I would need some converter, which makes a flat image from the cubic projection, then import this image somehow. Do you know such kind of a converter application?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pano2vr-converting-panorama-pic-google-cardboard-vr-sakari-castrén and http://ggnome.com/pano2vr May be of use. Might have to jailbreak your phone or share photos into the cardboard app.

Comment: As far as I can see Pano2VR does not support QTVR input format: http://ggnome.com/wiki/Input%20formats%20%28Pano2VR%29

Comment: I contacted the developers this morning and asked. They said
Just use the QTVR as the input image and then use the HTML5 output with the Cardboard html template and you should be good to go. (see: https://ggnome.com/doc/pano2vr/5/hmd-how/)

Comment: Thank you, that's a good start, Pano2VR works fine for exporting a flat image. Now I have to import it somehow. I've figured out, that Google Cardboard doesn't want to import the image no matter which name I set for it and which size I resize it. Maybe because it needs some special pseudo-3D-sound-included format?

Comment: Try getting an app like iExplorer or iFunbox and putting the file directly inside of the app. Another alternative (and I'm unsure if this will work) is to put the file into your phone via itunes. (Not sure if google cardboard and itunes get along though)

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. First of all, I don't know the format Cardboard uses. Second, if I put a JPEG image in it's director, it will not trigger actions to add it to it's database or web services.

Comment: Maybe try putting it through icloud and adding it to photos on your device and see if google photos can find it?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not find. I see the list of my albums, I can select one of them, the app scans it, and then tells me that nothing is found. I've found no help which kind of files is it looking for.

Comment: Is apparently jpg files.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Google-Cardboard-Photospheres/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Here is another link to the panos someone else has successfuly added to their phone. http://pages.swcp.com/~adric/pano/      -- it might be important to have PANO_xxxxxxxx.jpg

Comment: Since it is scanning my library very fast, I think it does not need the image data, only some metadata, like file dimensions or file name. I've tried to replicate the exact parameters of a panorama which the app saved when I record a new scene with it, but failed, Cardboard didn't find the file I prepared.

Comment: No, you are linking PhotoSpheres, which is a different app. This technology is currently under the name "Street View" on iOS. Google Cardboard Camera uses different tech (despite the similiarities). The panoramas which you can take with CC are not spherical, only cylindrical, but they have some kind of pseudo-3D effect and background sound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46739/discussion-between-bret7600-and-gklka).